# How can I center my menu inside my topbar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my own little Code Player. Similar to jsfiddle site. Right now I am having trouble with CSS.

[image]

I would like to center my menubar ( the buttons HTML, CSS, Javascript, result) in the topbar.

I just started learning HTML, CSS and Javascript. Do you have an idea how I can solve this problem?

```css
#header {
  width: 99%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#appname {
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  font-style: italic;
}

#run {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 20px 10px 0px;
}

#menu {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: -1px;
}

#menu ul {
  height: 30px;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="appname">
    <b>Code Player</b>
  </div>
  <div id="run">
    <button>RUN</button>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="buttonHTML">HTML</li>
      <li id="buttonCSS">CSS</li>
      <li id="buttonJS">Javascript</li>
      <li id="buttonResult">Result</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="break"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "top bar"?

Comment: On your `<ul>` do `display:inline-block` and `-webkit-padding-start:0`

Comment: FWIW, it looks like a number of the properties in `#header` are trying to tackle the default margin applied to `<body>` by the browser. May I suggest `body { margin: 0; }` along with `#header { height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this styles for your menu:

```
#menu {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: -1px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the width and margin on `#menu`. Then you can use `display: flex; justify-content: center; padding: 0;` on `#menu ul` to center it's contents. I also removed the `float`s from `#menu li` because they're no longer necessary.

```css
#header {
  width: 99%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#appname {
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  font-style: italic;
}

#run {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 20px 10px 0px;
}

#menu {
  padding-top: -1px;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="appname">
    <b>Code Player</b>
  </div>
  <div id="run">
    <button>RUN</button>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="buttonHTML">HTML</li>
      <li id="buttonCSS">CSS</li>
      <li id="buttonJS">Javascript</li>
      <li id="buttonResult">Result</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="break"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `text-align: center` to your header and change the div containing the list to `display:inline-block` it should do the trick. I also removed the padding, margin, and width:

```css
#header {
  width: 99%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  text-align:center;
}

#appname {
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  font-style: italic;
}

#run {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 20px 10px 0px;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: -1px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#menu ul {
  height: 30px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="appname">
    <b>Code Player</b>
  </div>
  <div id="run">
    <button>RUN</button>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="buttonHTML">HTML</li>
      <li id="buttonCSS">CSS</li>
      <li id="buttonJS">Javascript</li>
      <li id="buttonResult">Result</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="break"></div>
```